# How do I check if all posts from a joined table has the same value in a column?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2, business-intelligence

I'm building a BI report for a client where there is a 1-n related join involved.
The joined table has a field for employee ID (EmplId).

The query that I've built for this report is supposed to give a 1 in its field "OneEmployee" if all the related posts have the same employee in the EmplId field, null if it's different employees, i.e:

```
TaskTrans
    TaskTransHours > EmplId: 'John'
    TaskTransHours > EmplId: 'John'
```

This should give a 1 in the said field in the query

```
TaskTrans
    TaskTransHours > EmplId: 'John'
    TaskTransHours > EmplId: 'George'
```

This should leave the said field blank

The idea is to create a field where a case function checks this and returns the correct value. But my problem is whereas there is a way to check for this through SQL.

Comment: What database product & version are you using? E.g. Oracle, Sql Server 2008 R2, etc.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2008 R2. Though the query is written inside Visual Studio. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: @Flaskis, Can you include the query you have written so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
select not count(*) from your_table
where employee_id = GIVEN_ID
  and your_field not in ( select min(your_field) 
                          from your_table
                          where employee_id = GIVEN_ID);
```

Note: my first idea was to use `LIMIT 1` in the inner query, but MYSQL didn't like it, so min it was - the points to use any, but only one. Min should work, but the field should be indexed, then this query will actually execute rather fast, as only indexes would be used (obviously employee_id should also be indexed).

Note2: Do not get too confused with `not` in front of `count(*)`, you want 1 when there is none that is different, I count different ones, and then give you the `not count(*)`, which will be one if count is 0, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a job for a [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT
  …,
  CASE COUNT(DISTINCT TaskTransHours.EmplId) OVER () WHEN 1 THEN 1 END
    AS OneEmployee
FROM …
```